# Unit testing CakePHP application that uses stored procedures

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, cakephp, stored-procedures

Does anyone know of the correct way to develop unit tests for a CakePHP 2.3.1 application that utilises MySQL stored procedures?

I've looked on the cake site but the documentation on testing isn't huge. I've checked out SO and Google as well - can't seem to find mention of the problem/situation.

The unit testing is using fixtures, not a real database for the data.

Any help/pointers are really appreciated!

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload the Fixture’s create() method. Don’t forget to call parent’s create() and remove the final delimiter after the closing END in the create procedure statement.

e.g.:

```
public function create($db){
    parent::create($db);
    // create stored procedures ...
    $db->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE … <insert SQL here> … END", array('log' => false));
}
```

The create() method can execute any statements you need after the fixture table is created.

I hope it will work

Comment: Some feedback, to complete the answer for others:

Unless you want to leave the stored procedure behind after the tests (and cause a sql error second time around), also put a "drop procedure" statement in an overridden drop() method for the fixture.

Note: your db user will need alter privs on the test database!

J

Comment: I had to remove the DELIMITER commands from above and below my script. (I usually start stored procedures with `DELIMITER $$` and end with `DELIMITER ;`. and that was causing a "Syntax error or access violation: 1064" from CakePHP.)